# .net resize video resolution before saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video-processing

I have a website ASP.NET MVC c# where users can upload a video interview of themselves of around 1 min, max 100MB in size. I am thinking to save a resized version of the video (max 500px width or height) thus saving space and not to make the page that shows multiple videos run slowly. The videos are saved in Azure Blobs

Can you give me some solution ideas? For image resizing I am using ImageProcessor but I'm not sure it works with videos.

Comment: Are you willing to reduce quality as a payoff?

Comment: even if so, resizing a video is a expensive resource process that is going to put a heavy load in your web server, the only thing that you can do, is file compression

Comment: try out [NReco Video converter](https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx)

Comment: As MrVoid said, a web application is the wrong place to put this sort of potentially long-running computation-expensive post-processing. You could offload to another service/resource on Azure or even an Azure Function